# Cookie based router guard doesnt work in Angular17 using canActivateFn

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button:

```
 <button
      type="submit"
      class="bg-blue-600 px-10 text-xl py-3 rounded-md text-white font-semibold"
      routerLink="/user-dashboard/main"
    >
```

a service:

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}
  url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login';
  token: string = '';
  isAuthenticated = signal<Boolean>(false);
  changeIsAAuthenticated() {
    this.isAuthenticated.set(false);
    console.log(this.isAuthenticated);
  }
  async login(formObject: any) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`${this.url}`, formObject, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      console.log('http cookie set!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  verifyToken = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${this.url}`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      if (res.status !== 200) return;
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return false;
    }
  };
}
```

and a route guard:

```
export const loginAuthGuard: CanActivateFn = async (route, state) => {
  let authService = inject(AuthService);
  try {
    const isValid = await authService.verifyToken();
    if (!isValid) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
    console.log('go next!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return false;
  }
};
```

and a router:

```
 path: 'user-dashboard',
    component: UserDashboardComponent,
    title: 'user-dashboard',
    canActivate: [loginAuthGuard],
    children:
```

if i enter the correct credentials, theres no console.log. If i enter the bad crenedtials, i go in anyway and theres 401 code in console, but i go in. Why does this guard doesnt work?

Comment: edit:  
console.log('go next!');
    return true;